# br with javascript showed as HTMLBRElement

Tags: javascript, html

```
let br = document.createElement('br');
let tr = tbody.insertRow(tbody.rows.length);
let td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
td.textContent = item +br;
```

The result that I get besides the item is `[object HTMLBRElement]` instead of the `br` itself.
How can I have a `br` after the item without using `innerHtml` ?

Comment: Use `appendChild()`.

Comment: `textContent` is for literal text, not HTML.

Comment: I tried with appendChild but nothing changed, I will edit the question with that function again

Comment: Wh don't you do something like `td.innerHTML = item + "<br>"`

Comment: @user12137152 because innerHtml will delete the previous items.. it's not recommanded to use it

Comment: But there are no previous elements, you just created the TD.

Comment: @Yosra MH Let's assume that there is something so you can do : `td.innerHTML += item + "<br>"` or `td.innerHTML = td.innerHTML + item + "<br>"` (both are equivalent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`item + br` performs string concatenation, so the `br` element is converted to a string. Converting an object to a string produces `[object PrototypeName]`.

To add an HTML element, use the `appendChild()` method.

```
td.textContent = item;
td.appendChild(br);
```

Comment: using td.appendChild(br); did'nt change anything .. I tried it

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to loose the previous childs, you can use document fragment like this

```
let br = document.createElement('br');
let tr = tbody.insertRow(tbody.rows.length);
let td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
fragment.appendChild(item); // make sure that item is an html element, if it is a text , wrap it inside span or p or div element
fragment.appendChild(br);
td.appendChild(fragment) // all childs of fragment are now transferred to td
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment for more info

Note that I could have directly used appendChild one by one for td, but I didn't because it makes browser render multiple times, but through DocumentFragment, when you add all the child in one go to the td, browser has to render only one time, making your application more efficient with having the same result.